# how to demux 100V to 300V DC signal into 8 channels?

Tags: transformer, dc, boost, multiplexer, step-up

I need to 8 channels of 100Vdc to 300vdc, load current 10mA to 80mA.

my idea is to use a step transformer to step up dc 5v 1A source to 300Vdc 50mA (typical application).

low voltage side of the transformer (5v side) will be controller with MOSFET using a microcontroller and the output side or high voltage side will connect to load.

I need 8 channel outputs with a single transformer setup.

how to demux 300Vdc channel into 8 channels? I am using a single channel at a moment

output will be used to sense muscles nerves

also, I want to know is it possible to use a boost converter to sense muscle like LT8331 9V to 16V Input, 135V Boost Converter

Comment: First re-do you power calculations. All figures given thus far show that you want to get more energy out then you put in.

Comment: Why do you need 8 channels? Is this for sensing or power?

Comment: @Voltage Spike this is for sensing

Comment: Please capitalise and punctuate properly. Not doing so creates a very bad impression. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lead with "my idea is to use a step transformer to step up dc 5v 1A source to 300Vdc 50mA (typical application)"

5V 1A = 5 Watts.  300V 50 mA = 15,000 mW = 15 Watts.

This won't work, son.  The First Law of Thermodynamics, Graduate Student Version, tells us "You can't get something for nothing."

Answer (score 2):

First of all transformers are for AC only.  Not DC.  If you want to step up DC you need a BOOST converter.  You don't use boost converters for sensing, you use transducers for converting any analog (aka real world) inputs into DC values your circuit and evaluate.

Comment: i did not get it "you use transducers for converting any analog (aka real world) inputs into DC values your circuit and evaluate." could you explain ?